# Rails Carrierwave White_List not throwing Exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, rubygems, carrierwave

Just started using carrierwave with Rails and things have been going smoothly with one minor exception.  I created a "ImageUploader" class which looks so:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::RMagick
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

and a controller action which looks like so:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  if params[:user].nil? || params[:user][:image].nil?
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  else
    if @user.update_attribute(:image, params[:user][:image])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated successfully!"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "Changes could not be saved."
      render :action => 'edit'
    end      
  end
end
```

In this case I mounted the uploader in my User.rb like so:

```
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

Problem is, according to the [Carrierwave README](http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.2/file/README.rdoc), uploaded files with extensions not in the extensions_white_list should make the record invalid.  In my case I have purposely been testing the app by uploading files with various extensions not on the white list and no error is being raised.  In fact, @user.update_attribute seems to pass and I am usually redirected to user_path(@user) with a flash[:success] message.  The image itself is not actually changed, but I would like to be able to catch the error and redirect to the 'edit' page in case of an incorrect extension type.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested I sort of found a workaround for this myself. Not the most elegant solution, but in any case here's what worked for me:

```
@user.image = params[:user][:image]
if @user.image_integrity_error
    flash[:error] = "Changes could not be saved."
    @user.errors.add(:upload, @user.image_integrity_error)
    render 'edit'
else
    @user.update_attribute(:image, @user.image)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated successfully!"
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI the CarrierWave documentation states the following:

> The Active Record validations use the Rails i18n framework. Add these keys to your translations file:

```
errors:
  messages:
    carrierwave_processing_error: 'Cannot resize image.'
    carrierwave_integrity_error: 'Not an image.'
    carrierwave_download_error: 'Couldn't download image.'
```